# db like ms access for php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

As you know ASP can use MS Access. It is useful for small websites. It reduces time and money.

Is there an alternative to MySQL that I can use like ms access for PHP? What I want is to use db as a file as ms access do.

Any opinion?

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but can you not use MS Access in this case?

Comment: @Matt, can PHP use MS Access?

Comment: Yep you can use the ODBC connection: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp  Michael also provided an alternate link for this, I believe his should be the accepted answer in this case.

Comment: Not only you can use odbc, but you can actually use PDO (with odbc driver) to connect to Access from PHP. Be prepared for some struggles with character encodings though. MS Access uses Windows codepages.

Comment: ODBC is not an option. It only supports IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try SQLite, and it supports PHP. Here's a link you can use as reference. Hope it helps!

Comment: But sqlite support bundled in PHP5, isn't it? There are still PHP4 servers.

Answer (score 9):

You can use SQLite3, which stores the whole database as a file. It's very useful for small databases with low scalability requirements. It isn't recommended for a high traffic site, however.

[Docs on the PHP SQLite3 API...](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php)

You can also, however, connect to MS Access [via ODBC from PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php).

Comment: But sqlite support bundled in PHP5, isn't it? There are still PHP4 servers.

Comment: PHP4? This would be irresponsible. Support was dropped a long time ago. Even 5.2 is no longer officially supported.

Comment: @Luois; you are right. But I still see lots of PHP4 servers. :)

Comment: @borayeris There are some PHP4 servers hanging around on still-supported Red Hat servers, for example, but they are evaporating rapidly.  There is a PECL extension for SQLite support in PHP4, but I really wouldn't worry too much about coding for PHP4. There are _far more_ things than SQLite that PHP4 doesn't support.